# jQuery css gradient

Tags: jquery, css

To have a gradient background on an element I do something like this:

```
.css('filter','progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=\'#FFFFFF\', endColorstr=\'#'+event.backgroundColor+'\', gradientType=1)')
.css('background-image','-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0.1, #FFFFFF), color-stop(0.99, #'+event.backgroundColor+'))')
.css('background-image','-moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #'+event.backgroundColor+' 100%)')
.css('background-image','-o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #'+event.backgroundColor+' 100%)')
```

Now, isn't jQuery suppose to eliminate all the work related to cross-browser compatibility issues? is there any better way to do that. Without using any additional plugins?

Comment: Jquery will eliminate/reduce js related cross browser issues it won't fix your css cross browser problems. As for what i know jQuery wont fix this problem for you.

Comment: You could just define all of that in your stylesheet. Not sure why you are using jQuery, unless you need to do this dynamically or something.

Comment: Don't use "background-image:" - use "background:".

Comment: put all of these in a stylesheet under a class, then toggle the class with jquery.

Comment: @SteveCostello If you use the shortcut syntax `background`, then if you change any of the background properties later, for example background-position, then you can also overwrite the gradient you set in background. The CSS Specifications suggest not using shorthand codes anymore.

Comment: @Brandon: Good call on the reason not to use the shortcut.

Comment: @helloandre - good solution in some cases, not others. When working with dynamic colors you can't make millions of CSS styles to account for the millions of color combos :)

Comment: @SteveCostello - Nevermind, I see now Brandon covered the same comment I had :P

Comment: @Michael - I don't know that that generalization is correct. For instance with "opacity" jquery fixes the cross browser issues in an equivalent way to what he's asking for here with the gradients. I'm betting that the jquery people just picked and chose which cross browser issues to accommodate in order to not bloat the code too much. Or also as likely: CSS gradient popularity is newer, and it could just not be implemented yet.

Comment: combining them into a single .css call will make it better. And, jquery does handle some vendor prefixes for you, but not for all properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a jQuery plugin used to work with gradient. i have never used it but it looks simple

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gradient

heres how to use it :

http://www.julien-verkest.fr/13/11/2007/jquery-gradient-le-plugin-qui-permet-de-creer-dynamiquement-des-backgrounds-degrades

or you could use use Gradientz

http://jquerystyle.com/2009/08/06/gradientz

Gradientz looks even more complete and easy to use. Up to you good luck buddy.

Comment: Gradientz looks like a nice plugin :)

Comment: It does im gonna have to finda project to try it in! the jQuery community is so awesome theres tons of really nice plugins.

Comment: Yep sure is! And its growing every day :)

Comment: those sites seem down

Answer (score 4):

Nope. jQuery doesn't have a native implementation of vendor-prefixes. Not very surprising, too; jQuery is a *JavaScript* library, designed to make *JavaScript* cross-browser.

Check out [CSS3 Finalize](https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Css3-Finalize) for a plugin.