# Javascript/ jQuery transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I was looking for a way to use the transition propriety for a gradient or an image, but because i didn't find one, i looked after a way in javascript/ jquery. I found a lot of tutorials, but I didn't know which of them is good because there was no demo.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016988/applying-css3-gradients-with-jquery .

Comment: Depending on the browsers you need to support, css3 transitions and transformations might be your best option. In a few years almost certainly so. But right now it might be your worst option. It really depends on your circumstances. Without understanding more about what your constraints are, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Transit](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) ?
I personally tried it and enjoyed it very much.
Here are some awesome [demos](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

If you only need to apply that specific transition to a single image, then using such a library is overkill obviously. If this applies to you, if I were in your place, I would just use the native CSS3 transitions. Besides IE versions < 10, I am not aware of current browsers that do not support CSS3 transitions. You can verify yourself by going at caniuse.com

If CSS animations aren’t supported in a browser, they will be applied instantly, so you get at least some graceful degradation.

Comment: It helps a bit, but it's not exactly what I want, I'm a newbie... I didn't find there how to transit a BG-gradient or an image. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Mike, I setup a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/ySakG/ OR see this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition-property2