# set all css3 background-image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi I want to set the `background-image` for all browser with jquery :

```
background-image:linear-gradient(green, blue); /* Norme W3C */
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(green, blue); /* Firefox */
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, green, blue); /* Chrome, Safari */
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(green, blue); /* Opera */
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(green, blue); /* IE */
```

and I set it like that :

`$("#"+elmt).css("background-image" , "linear-gradient("+hex+","+$('#test2').val()+")" );`

only for W3C but it work on firefox but not on Chrome.

How can I set all this setting?

Comment: I believe you will find this answer useful.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5735571/1145124

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**From the jQuery 1.8 Blog's release**](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/)

*Automatic CSS prefixing: When you use a CSS property, in either .css() or .animate(), we’ll use the correct prefixed property (when appropriate) for that browser. For example, take .css("user-select", "none"); in Chrome/Safari we’ll set the value as "-webkit-user-select", Firefox will use "-moz-user-select", and IE10 will use "-ms-user-select".*

Upgrade to the latest version and this should be handled automatically.

**Edit**

This should work automatically, the following *should* be implemented in jQuery 1.8,

```
var cssPrefixString = {};
var cssPrefix = function(propertie) {
    if (cssPrefixString[propertie] || cssPrefixString[propertie] === '') return cssPrefixString[propertie] + propertie;
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    var prefixes = ['', 'Moz', 'Webkit', 'O', 'ms', 'Khtml']; // Various supports...
    for (var i in prefixes) {
        if (typeof e.style[prefixes[i] + propertie] !== 'undefined') {
            cssPrefixString[propertie] = prefixes[i];
            return prefixes[i] + propertie;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

The usage

```
var cssTransform = cssPrefix('Transform'); // "MozTransform" or "WebkitTransform"
if (cssTransform ) {
    var cssProp = {};
    cssProp['border'] = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)';
    cssProp[cssPrefix('Transform')] = 'rotate(20deg)';
    cssProp[cssPrefix('borderRadius')] = '5px'; // Keep the camelCaze (jQuery like)
    cssProp[cssPrefix('boxShadow')] = '2px 2px 6px grey';
    $('div#myDiv').css(cssProp);
    // console.log(cssProp);
}
```

[Which came from the link -- a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/f6Z3D/)

So one of these two methods should work for you.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. They are prefixing css attribute names, but are you sure they do the same for the values?

Comment: @iMoses perhaps -- I'm making assumptions based on the statements they made, which is in and of its self a flaw. I've added code that fully supports auto-prefixing, which should be live in jQuery 1.8. Follow the fiddle and inspect the element, or uncomment the `// console.log()` line and this should be working, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead just use **-prefix-free**: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

It dynamically adds vendor prefixes to your CSS.