# CSS background via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a CSS attribute using jQuery but having an issue with the Background selector. Right now I have:

```
$('#nav_wrap').css({ 'position': 'fixed',
                     'margin-top':0,
                     'z-index':400,
                     'background-color': 'red',
                     'top':0,
                     'left':0 });
```

which gives the the color Red just fine, nothing wrong with the code. What I want to do is make it a gradient but when I change it to this:

```
 $('#nav_wrap').css({ 'position': 'fixed',
                      'margin-top':0,
                      'z-index':400,
                      'background': 'linear-gradient(top, #dc0000 0%,#650101 100%)',
                      'top':0, 'left':0 });
```

The background attribute doesnt get recognized. Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: What browser you're using? `linear-gradient` isn't cross browser.

Comment: You might need to use vendor selectors.

Comment: to the first comment, he's asking how to do it in jquery, how is that not clear? did you not read the question lol. Check out this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735521/jquery-css-gradient seems to have what you need.

Comment: assign that to a class, and just use addClass()

Comment: @Rooster I didn't think about that. Should be perfect.

Comment: @Nick and I agree with you as well. Using Chrome so that could be the problem why it was not picking up that CSS. Just adding a class probably would be best though since I have to have so many variations on the property for browser support.

Comment: @Shan Robertson jQuery is not a browser, it is a JavaScript helper library, gustavohenke asked what browser Packy is using as 'linear-gradient' isn't available in all browsers (some implementations have browser specific prefixes). jQuery is often quite good at working out what property to use in which browsers (like in the case of opacity), but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you demonstrated up to use classes instead of manually setting each CSS property for such purpose in the comments, here's how you would do it cross browser (IE8+):

**CSS**

```
.yourClass {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  z-index: 400;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dc0000, #650101);

  /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#dc0000), to(#650101));

  /* FF 3.6+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dc0000, #650101); 

  /* Opera 11.10 */ 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dc0000, #650101);

  /* Standard, IE 10 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dc0000, #650101);

  /* IE8 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdc0000', endColorstr='#ff650101', GradientType=0);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#nav_wrap').addClass("yourClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use classes and than add and remove class using jquery

```
$('#check').addClass('gradient'); //add class
$('#check').removeClass('gradient'); //remove class
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F38pk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#nav_wrap').css({ 'position': 'fixed',
                  'margin-top':0,
                  'z-index':400,
                  'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #dc0000 0%,#650101 100%)',
                  'top':0, 'left':0 });
```